# Laplacian Pyramid producing weird results?

Tags: java, android, matlab, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to make a Laplacian Pyramid based on this MATLAB code:

```matlab
% I is the image array, where its size is r x c x 3(<-RGB channels).
function pyr = laplacian_pyramid(I,nlev)

r = size(I,1);
c = size(I,2);

% recursively build pyramid
pyr = cell(nlev,1);
filter = [.0625, .25, .375, .25, .0625];
J = I;
for l = 1:nlev - 1
    % apply low pass filter, and downsample
    I = downsample(J,filter);
    odd = 2*size(I) - size(J);  % for each dimension, check if the upsampled version has to be odd
    % in each level, store difference between image and upsampled low pass version
    pyr{l} = J - upsample(I,odd,filter);
    J = I; % continue with low pass image
end
pyr{nlev} = J; % the coarest level contains the residual low pass image
```

Where, `downsample()` looks like this:

```matlab
function R = downsample(I, filter)

border_mode = 'symmetric';

% low pass, convolve with separable filter
R = imfilter(I,filter,border_mode);     %horizontal
R = imfilter(R,filter',border_mode);    %vertical

% decimate
r = size(I,1);
c = size(I,2);
R = R(1:2:r, 1:2:c, :);
```

And here is `upsample()`:

```matlab
function R = upsample(I,odd,filter)

% increase resolution
I = padarray(I,[1 1 0],'replicate'); % pad the image with a 1-pixel border
r = 2*size(I,1);
c = 2*size(I,2);
k = size(I,3);
R = zeros(r,c,k);
R(1:2:r, 1:2:c, :) = 4*I; % increase size 2 times; the padding is now 2 pixels wide

% interpolate, convolve with separable filter
R = imfilter(R,filter);     %horizontal
R = imfilter(R,filter');    %vertical

% remove the border
R = R(3:r - 2 - odd(1), 3:c - 2 - odd(2), :);
```

This MATLAB code is working properly. Just focus on the `downsample()` function, since my OpenCV version of that function is why my problem happens.

---

Now here is my attempt on the OpenCV version of this MATLAB code:

```
private List<Mat> laplacianPyramid(Mat mat,int depth)
    {
        //mat.type() is CV_8UC3 (16).
        List<Mat> pyramid = new ArrayList<Mat>();
        //I make a clone so I don't ruin the original matrix.
        Mat clone = mat.clone();
        Mat J = clone;
        for(int i=0;i<=depth-2;i++)
        {
            clone = image_reduce(J);
            Mat temp = new Mat();
            Point odd = new Point(clone.size().height*2 - J.height(), clone.size().width*2 - J.width());
            Core.subtract(J, image_expand(clone, odd), temp);
            pyramid.add(temp);
            J = clone;
        }
        pyramid.add(J);
        return pyramid;
    }
```

Here is my OpenCV version of `upsample()`:

```
private Mat image_expand(Mat image, Point odd){
        //I make a clone so I don't ruin the original image.
        Mat imageClone = image.clone();
        copyMakeBorder(imageClone, imageClone, 1, 1, 1, 1, BORDER_REPLICATE);
        Mat kernelX = getGaussianKernel();
        Mat kernelY = new Mat();
        Core.transpose(kernelX, kernelY);
        Mat UIntVer = new Mat(imageClone.size(), CV_8UC3);
        imageClone.convertTo(UIntVer, CV_8UC3);
        Imgproc.resize(UIntVer, UIntVer, new Size(imageClone.width()*2, imageClone.height()*2), 0, 0, Imgproc.INTER_NEAREST);

        //Now implement the zero padding between each columns and rows, just like the MATLAB version.
        Mat mask = new Mat(2,2, CV_8UC1);
        int[][] array = new int[2][2];
        array[0][0] = 255;
        array[1][0] = 0;
        array[0][1] = 0;
        array[1][1] = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<2; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                mask.put(i, j, array[i][j]);
            }
        }
        //mask becomes twice the size of image.
        Mat biggerMask = new Mat();
        Core.repeat(mask, imageClone.height(), imageClone.width(), biggerMask);
        List<Mat> rgbUIntVer = new ArrayList<Mat>();
        Core.split(UIntVer,rgbUIntVer);
        Core.bitwise_and(rgbUIntVer.get(0), biggerMask, rgbUIntVer.get(0));
        Core.bitwise_and(rgbUIntVer.get(1), biggerMask, rgbUIntVer.get(1));
        Core.bitwise_and(rgbUIntVer.get(2), biggerMask, rgbUIntVer.get(2));
        Core.merge(rgbUIntVer, UIntVer);

        int r = imageClone.height()*2;
        int c = imageClone.width()*2;
        Mat result = new Mat(r, c, CV_32FC3);
        UIntVer.convertTo(UIntVer, CV_32FC3);
        Scalar four = new Scalar(4);
        Core.multiply(UIntVer, four, UIntVer);
        Imgproc.sepFilter2D(UIntVer,result,-1,kernelX,kernelY,new Point(-1,-1) ,0,BORDER_DEFAULT);
        Rect roi = new Rect(2, 2, c-4-(int)odd.y, r-4-(int)odd.x);
        result = new Mat(result, roi);
        return result;
    }
```

---

The problem with this OpenCV version code is that the result is just pure bluish. Laplacian Pyramids are supposed to save edge detection results, but an example result is like this. The image above is the original input, and the image below is the bottom floor of the resulting pyramid.

[image]

I checked that the input image is read correctly. Something is off with my code, but I can't find where. Any help would be highly appreciated!

I am suspecting that some processing functions are working only on the R channel, and not the GB channel.

---

I found out that what's wrong is `image_expand()`. It simply just outputs a red versioned image, which explains why the result image is bluish, since the result image is the difference between the original image and the output of `image_expand()`. So the problem is in `image_expand()`.

---

Just in case, here is my `getGaussianKernel()` code:

```
private Mat getGaussianKernel(){
        float[] kernel = new float[5];
        kernel[0]= 0.0625f;
        kernel[1]=0.25f;
        kernel[2]=0.375f;
        kernel[3]=0.25f;
        kernel[4]=0.0625f;
        Mat mat = new Mat(5,1,CV_32FC1);
        mat.put(0,0,kernel);
        return mat;
    }
```

Comment: Without looking at your code, I am just assuming there is something worng with channels. Perhaps you only apply the code to a single channel at some point, or you dont consider BGR-RGB conversions, or some other thing related to that.

Comment: You should probably run that function with some code added that displays intermediate images. Compare those to your expectation of what they should look like, to narrow down where within the function it goes wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. As Mr. @Ander Biguri and Mr. @Cris Luengo (Sorry if I'm assuming your gender) has told me, the problem was at

```
UIntVer.convertTo(UIntVer, CV_32FC3);
Scalar four = new Scalar(4);
Core.multiply(UIntVer, four, UIntVer);
```

in `image_expand()`. Apparently, for multiplying a Scalar value, you have to perform `Core.split()` to an image matrix, and apply the multiplication for each channel, then `Core.merge()` it. This is because `Core.multiply()` only deals with 1 channel at a time. I hope this helps other people finding trouble with `Core.multiply()`.